# PHP & Mysql can't get name of table with UNION

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
if($result = mysql_query(
"SELECT `condition` FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = '1')
 UNION ALL
SELECT `condition` FROM `table2` WHERE `id` = '1')
 UNION ALL
SELECT `condition` FROM `table3` WHERE `id` = '1')"
){ 
      $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
      for($i = 0;  $i < $num; $i++){     
        $table = mysql_field_table($result, $i);
        echo  $table.' cond: '.mysql_result($result, $i, 'condition').', ';
      }
}
```

Here I can get results of query(condition), but I do also want to get the tables' names, in order to know to which table the result belongs, I tried it: mysql_field_table($result, $i), but it does not return anything.
So please help me to get name of table, thank you in advance.

Comment: Use something directly in sql like `SELECT CONCAT(condition,'t1') FROM..UNION ALL SELECT CONCAT(condition,'t2') FROM...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a set of *calculated* columns so there's no source table you can trace back. You need to add the information yourself:

```
SELECT `condition`, 'table1' AS source
FROM `table1`
WHERE `id` = '1'

UNION ALL

SELECT `condition`, 'table2'
FROM `table2`
WHERE `id` = '1'

UNION ALL

SELECT `condition`, 'table3'
FROM `table3`
WHERE `id` = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
  SELECT `condition`, '1' tablnumber FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = '1'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT `condition`,'2' FROM `table2` WHERE `id` = '1'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT `condition`,'3' FROM `table3` WHERE `id` = '1'
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f8027/8)